# Binary data from webservice(octedstream) into SQL statement android

Tags: android, sqlite, binary-data, create-table

Is it possible to use binary data (contentype = octet-stream) that I receive from a webservice as a SQLite statement? Or should i first convert it into a string? (but the problem here is that it consists of unrecognized symbols, for example images, ...

This binary data consists of "create table ..."

Thanx, JP

Comment: You can convert the bytes to string and run as SQL. Though trusting an external source for raw SQL is prone to all kinds of problems so it's better avoided. What do you mean by "images"? Funny characters or binary image data?

Comment: It could be binary image data because the images are also stored as binary data into the database.. but when i convert it into a string i displays these squares with a question mark in it..